# rails each_with_index cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord, actionview

I'm trying to cache the following:

```
<% @equipment.sports.zip(@equipment.sport_equipments).each_with_index do |(sport, equipment), index| %>
   <% cache[cache_version_tool, equipment.cache_key, sport.cache_key, index] do %>
      <%= render 'sport', sport: sport, equipment: equipment, cached: true %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The block works fine with out cache but when I had it I receive:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (no block given (yield)):
```

How do I pass the `each_with_index` block to the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the `each_with_index`. You are calling the cache method wrong.

Your call of

```
cache[cache_version_tool, equipment.cache_key, sport.cache_key, index] do
```

gets translated to

```
cache().[](cache_version_tool, equipment.cache_key, sport.cache_key, index) do
```

`cache()` receives no arguments and does not receive a block. Inside it checks for cache with no arguments (which obviously does not exist) and then calls `yield`. Since `cache()` did not receive a block (the `[]` access did), then it raises an error of `no block given (yield)`.

Add a space between `cache` and `[`

```
cache [cache_version_tool, equipment.cache_key, sport.cache_key, index] do
```

Now it gets interpreted as

```
cache([cache_version_tool, equipment.cache_key, sport.cache_key, index]) do
```

And everything should work.

Or better yet, add the parentheses for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, honestly didn't catch the space.